# Определение размеров монитора и передача значений переменным PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Доброго всем времени суток.

Как определить размеры монитора на javascript, и передать эти значения переменным на php? При этом выводить эти переменные или нет, я должен решить сам. т.е. вывод не должен быть обязательным.

Comment: Вам их в стилях использовать же?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если jQuery, то:

```
$.get('_script_', {width: screen.width, height: screen.height}, function(data){
    // в переменной data пришел ответ от скрипта
});
```

Если я неправильно понял, переформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос.

Comment: прописал это в чистой странице. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting T_VARIABLE or ... хочется именно javascript, и без подключения к ней ленинской энциклопедии, что бы при желании я в страницу мог вписать, что то вроде <? eсho $width."x".$height ; ?> и получилось, что то типа: 1280x800

Comment: `<?...?>` - это не javascript. Можно сделать так: `<?echo 'Размеры окна: <script>document.write(screen.width+"x"+screen.height);</script>';?>`

Comment: уже ближе, уже работает! но не то, эти переменные мне охота использовать дальше, так что простой вывод не вариант. вот я и написал в первом посте, что: я должен решить сам. т.е. вывод не должен быть обязательным.

Comment: Тогда ловите "жестяной вариант" =) :  

    <script>
    var href = location.href;
    if(!(/\?/.test(location.href))) href += '?';
    if(!(/width=/.test(href)) || !(/height=/.test(href)))
        location.replace(href + '&width=' + screen.width + '&height=' + screen.height);
    </script>
    
    <?
    $width = (int) $_GET['width'];
    $height = (int) $_GET['height'];
    ?>

Все равно без js никак.

Comment: я не против js, главное, что бы я мог писать или не писать строчку с выводом переменных, и работать с переменными. "жестяной вариант" - пока единственный, хоть и не идеальный. вот переменные в строке адреса это немного не то, что хотел

Comment: так используй сессии

Answer (score 1):

использовать библиотеку через activexobject :) но это для ИЕ.

Comment: ну тогда проще "в ручную" подойти к монитору и глянуть 8-)

Comment: попросить пользователя выбрать размер его экрана

Answer (score 1):

**Хак:**

HTML (`<head>`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mycss.php?w='+screen.width+'&h='+screen.height+'" />');
</script>
```

mycss.php

```
<?
@session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8');
$_SESSION['SCREEN_WIDTH'] = (!empty($_GET['w'])) ? intval($_GET['w']) : 1024;
$_SESSION['SCREEN_HEIGHT'] = (!empty($_GET['h'])) ? intval($_GET['h']) : 768;
?>
body { width: <?=$_SESSION['SCREEN_WIDTH']?>px; }
<? /* ну и так далее. Естественно, переменные будут доступны в сессии всем остальным скриптам после этого */ ?>
```

Comment: сделал. не работает 8-/ (просто чистая страница). а в один файл это нельзя поместить?

Comment: Что значит "не работает"?)

Скрипт надо засунуть в ваш шаблон, в тег `<head></head>`. файл mycss.php - в корневую папку сайта. Или дайте ссылку где поставили, укажу ошибки.

Comment: <a href="http://sh4dow.ru/test.php">пример рабочего кода</a>

Answer (score 0):

Размеры монитора ты никак не определишь :) А разрешение экрана - пожалуйста. screen.width и  screen.height. На сервер эти переменные можно отправить например через Ajax.

Comment: да, разрешение, попутал немного. вот я и хотел спросить как написать эту самую отправку, т.к. Ajax для меня даль далекая.

Comment: Например, через JQuery. Удобно, вполне.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/